# output redirection syntax in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I've been trying to experiment and see what the difference would be between

```
command >file 2> file
```

and

```
command >file 2>&1
```

I haven't been able to. I understand that the second says to send error to where file descriptor 1 (stdout) is already going, and the first would create a new empty file for it, but how can this be seen?

Also, where can I find more information to learn about file descriptors/io syntax and how it works?

Comment: There's no way to see them unless you hack the shell's source code and add debugging messages. Try looking for manual pages of C's common functions.

Comment: are you using a command that writes any output to StdErr (`2>errs`)? `/bin/ls -l NONEXISTANTFILE` will give you output on StdErr for instance. Good luck.

Comment: I haven't found one that writes to both @shellter , so I want to see where there will be an issue when both stdout and stderr attempt to write

Comment: `ls -l NonExistantFile myExistingFile` will use  stdOut `> file` and stdErr `2> errFile`. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that `>file 2>&1` opens the file just once, but then allows access to that single connection to the file (technically, the ["open file description" in the kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195057/what-is-an-open-file-description)) via both file descriptor #1 (stdout) and #2 (stderr). Since writes to both stdout and stderr are going via the same connection ("open file description"), they write to the file in a consistent, coordinated way (and similar coordination applies to files opened for input on multiple descriptors).

`>file 2>file`, on the other hand, opens the file *twice* (creating two separate open file descriptions in the kernel), so writing to the file via the two file descriptors is not coordinated, and they can basically step on each others' feet.

An example may help to clarify what I mean. Here's a short subshell command that prints something to stdout, then a bit to stderr, then more to stdout. Try it first with `>file 2>&1` and it does what you'd expect:

```
$ (echo abc; echo 123456 >&2; echo def) >file 2>&1
$ cat file
abc
123456
def
```

No surprise there, right? Now let's try it with separate connections to the file:

```
$ (echo abc; echo 123456 >&2; echo def) >file 2>file
$ cat file
1234def
```

That's probably not what you were expecting. What's happened here is that the first `echo` command sent "abc" followed by a newline character to stdout, and it got written into the first four bytes of the file. The second `echo` then sent "123456" followed by a newline to stderr; since the stderr connection was separate, it was still pointed to the beginning of the file, so it got written into the first seven bytes of the file (overwriting the "abc<newline>" that was already there). Then the third `echo` sent "def" and a newline to stdout; since the stdout connection was pointed to byte #5 of the file (one byte past where the last write to that connection ended), it gets written starting there, which overwrites the "56<newline>" part of what the second `echo` wrote there.

So having the same file open multiple times can lead to really confusing results. This is why you should always use `>file 2>&1` instead of `>file 2>file`.

Comment: So what I'm noticing is that there's no issue with `>file 2>file` if one or the other doesn't write. Why does it work this way? Do they only "stomp on eachother" when both write? I thought that they each would create a new instance of `file` by `>` notation and overwrite any old `file`, which is in fact what they do if `file` exists.

Comment: They don't create new instances of `file`, they open the existing file (if there is one) and delete any previous contents by calling `open()` with the [`O_TRUNC` flag](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Open_002dtime-Flags.html) (which "truncates" the file to zero length). Since both `open()`s happen before anything gets written over either stdout or stderr, they don't step on each other in *that* particular way. Note that if the command called [`ftruncate()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html) on either FD, that might delete contents written via the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of seeing one different

```
$ some-command > file > file
something to stderr if some-commands outputs
$ set -o noclobber
$ some-command > file > file
bash: file: cannot overwrite existing file
$ rm file
$ some-command > f1 2>&1
# no error
```

Comment: I see what you're trying to demonstrate, so why is it that if I run an arbitrary command `echo 'hello' >file 2>file`, then the stderr (which nothing is written to) doesn't overwrite the file?