# Why does the output of `paste` differ when using the standard input?

Tags: bash, shell, file, sh, stdin

From [man](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/paste-invocation.html#paste-invocation):

> `paste` writes to standard output lines consisting of sequentially corresponding lines of each given file, separated by a TAB character. Standard input is used for a file name of ‘-’ or if no input files are given.

If my understanding is correct (which seems to apply when not `paste`ing from the standard input) this means that, for instance, the command `paste file1 file2` will output
a number of lines of which the n-th consists of the n-th line of `file1`, followed by a TAB, and then the n-th line of `file2`.

However, if we were to replace each of the files with a `-` denoting the standard input, each line of the output would be consisting of two consecutive lines of the standard input, separated by a TAB, instead of the same line repeated twice. Why is that?

For example, given the file `foo.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Running the command `paste foo.txt foo.txt` will give the following output:

```
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
```

But running `paste - - < foo.txt` results in:

```
1    2
3    4
```

I'm thinking that `paste - - < foo.txt`  *"opens"* the file only once, while `paste foo.txt foo.txt` opens two instances of the same file, and thus two "*cursors*" are being used, but I'm not sure if that is true, or if it was why it happens.

Comment: `paste - -` doesn't open `foo.txt` at all; it only reads from the stream provided by the shell construct that is `< foo.txt`

Comment: The "two cursors" view is essentially correct. Try `paste - foo.txt - <foo.txt` and `paste foo.txt - - <foo.txt` to see more complex cases. Also, check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75393382/output-redirection-syntax-in-shell/75393852), about a similar situation with an output file that's opened once vs. twice.

Comment: The key point is that `paste` does *not* work differently; what's different is the file handles you've provided to `paste` in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and thus two "cursors" are being used, but I'm not sure if that is true

This is exactly true.

In more technical terms, opening a file creates a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). File descriptor has an associated [file position indicator](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05) (cursor) "to facilitate an orderly progression through the file". `paste - -` causes `paste` to read from the same standard input file descriptor twice, thus incrementing the same file position indicator twice. While `paste foo.txt foo.txt` makes paste open two file descriptors referencing the same file, but both file descriptors have separate file position indicators.