# bash redirect to the same file in a bad manner

Tags: bash, io-redirection

In bash, I know that `foo 1>a.txt 2>&1` outputs both stdout and stderr to the same file.
But, if I replace this by `foo 1>a.txt 2>a.txt` , it behaves strangely.

GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

A sample code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function foo {
  echo stdout1
  echo stdout2
  echo stdout3
  echo stderr1 >&2
  echo stderr2 >&2
  echo stdout4
}

foo 1>a.txt 2>a.txt
```

Then, the content of a.txt is

```
stderr1
stderr2
stdout3
stdout4
```

A strange point is I would expect that stdout does not appear at all or,
behaves like `1> a.txt 2>&1`, but it is not so.
A problem is that a.txt is open in write mode twice.
I want to know what happens in this redirections.

Comment: See ["output redirection syntax in shell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75393382/output-redirection-syntax-in-shell/75393852).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior but looks strange just because the number of characters of the English words `stderr` and `stdout` are same.

The root cause is `a.txt` is open twice, giving `bash` two *file handles* which both point to `a.txt`. They are completely **independent**, meaning the seek positions are not synced.

Let's see it step by step. When

```bash
echo stdout1
echo stdout2
echo stdout3
```

is executed, the content of the file becomes

```
stdout1
stdout2
stdout3
```

Then

```bash
echo stderr1 >&2
echo stderr2 >&2
```

is executed but the seek position of `stderr` is still `0` so the first and second line is overwritten, giving

```
stderr1
stderr2
stdout3
```

Finally,

```bash
echo stdout4
```

gives

```
stderr1
stderr2
stdout3
stdout4
```

because the seek position of `stdout` is at the start of the 4th line due to the previous execution of `echo stdout1; echo stdout2; echo stdout3`.

Comment: I see, the two file descriptors are writing bytes based on their respective seek positions.
I understood the same thing at the link that Davisson mentioned.
By the way, if we redirect twice in overwrite mode, is the file initialized when we declare the second redirection (i.e. redirection 2>a.txt)?

Comment: @naba What do you mean by "initialized"? Assuming `a.txt` doesn't exist at first, `1> a.txt` creates and opens `a.txt` and then `2> a.txt` just opens the existing `a.txt`.

Comment: In my context, "initialize" means that if a.txt exists and not empty, then it is truncated to zero size. So, in that script, `1>a.txt` creates the file a.txt, and then does `2>a.txt` initialize it ?

Comment: @naba As far as I know, your understanding is correct. `bash` is written in `C` and [`std::fopen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen), which opens a file, truncates the contents of a file when it already exists. But for perfectly accurate info, you may want to read the source code of `bash` [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/).

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply and references.